# Weird gaps with float left

Tags: php, html, css, css-float

I am completely blocked on this problem, I am working with a CMS, and I am generating the articles, and I want them to be in two colums, so

here is the html code ( I deleted a bit of the php parts not to confuse you ):

```
  <div id="contenu_col">


    <?php   

            echo '<div class="col1">
<a href="exhibition.php?ID='.$ID.'"><img src="square/'.$IMGACSQ.'" ></a><br/>
            <p><a href="exhibition.php?ID='.$ID.'">'.aff($DATE).'<br/>'.aff($nom_projet).' - '.aff($ARTISTE).'</p></a></div>'; 

</div>
```

that generate an html code that look like that :

```
    <div class="col1">
<a href="exhibition.php?ID=109">
<img src="square/E_3094_x.jpg" >
</a><br/>

<p><a href="exhibition.php?ID=109">11.12. - 29.01.11.<br/>New impressions - New works -  new artists - new space 5 and a happy new year)</p></a>

</div>

<div class="col1">
<a href="exhibition.php?ID=108">
<img src="square/BG_IoanGrosu06_x.jpg" >
</a><br/>
<p><a href="exhibition.php?ID=108">30.10. - 04.12.10.<br/>Come here tomorrow - Ioan Grosu</p></a></div>
```

and the css :

```
    .col1{
width:300px;
float:left; 
padding: 3%;
display: block;

}


.col1 img{
width:100%;

}

.col1:after{
clear: both;
}

#contenu_col {
width:850px;
top:150px;
z-index:50;
left:460px; 
position:absolute;  
padding-bottom: 20px;   
}

#contenu_col img{
width:100%;

}
```

( because I can't post images...)

It works 70% of the website; then sometimes some weird gap appears....
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong :(

RESOLVED.THANK YOU!!

Comment: Can you be more specific about the "weird gaps"?

Comment: You can see them on the url, I can't post images because I'm too new!

Comment: Don't combine multiple questions please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your col1 class and add a height,for example `height:300px;`

```
    .col1 {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    padding: 3%;
    display: block;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Also your `DIV#encar` isn't well styled.

Answer (score 0):

it appears because .col1 height is not unified, try to add this to your css

```
.col1{
  height: some value
}
```